# line chart(any chart) needs to display tool tip only when we hover

Tags: tooltip, anychart

How to show tool tip only when we hover over any marker in line chart(any chart) and hide it when no data exist on graph?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Tooltip ?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you should adjust the hoverMode of the chart. Just the following lines to your chart configuration code:

```
  // adjust chart interactivity
  var interactivity = chart.interactivity();
  // Set hover mode by X.
  interactivity.hoverMode('single');
```

For details, check the sample in the comment below.

Comment: Thanks!! thats works but i also have a crosshair on the chart and want to display the tooltip when crosshair line is hover over the data.

Comment: In the following sample, the tooltip is displayed when the point marker is hovered by the crosshair vertical and horizontal line - https://playground.anychart.com/Fsys6DbO/1

Comment: can we get tooltip without hovering on marker manually, i mean when the cursor is not on the marker but the vertical line is on the marker. For example if i have 2 markers drawn at the same time with different values, i should get the tooltip for both at resplective places when the vertical line is hovered over those marker.

Comment: in this case, you'll need to set 'by-x' for the hoverMode and make the tooltip be union by writing this: tooltip.displayMode("union");
please check the sample: https://playground.anychart.com/M7fGYZhS